# What is the suggested way to build and send a http request in Python

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest

I wrote a small module about 1 year age.
When I tried to add some feature to it these days, I found there is a big change in python's `urllib` and I was confused about how to build a request.

In the old module `FancyURLopener` was used as my base class, yet I found it was **Deprecated since version 3.3.**

So I read the document again, and try to build a request instead of a opener.

However, when I tried to add headers, only one function `Request.add_header(key, val)` was provided. I have headers copied from fiddler like this:

```
GET some_url HTTP/1.1
Host: sosu.qidian.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: zh-cn,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: anothe_url
Cookie: a lot of data
Connection: keep-alive
```

So do I have to add them to the request one by one?

Also I found another openner `urllib.request.build_opener()` which can add a lot of headers in one time. But I could not set method 'get' or 'post'.

I am a newbie on python, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

By far the best way to make http requests in Python is to install and use this module:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

You can write code like this:

```
headers = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Referer': 'anothe_url',
    # etc
}
response = requests.get(some_url, headers=headers)
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers